# How to loop through arrays starting at different index while still looping through entire array?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I had an array of 5 strings.  How can I start a for loop at index 3 and go around and end up at index 2?  Let me give an example.

```
var myArry = ["cool", "gnarly", "rad", "farout", "awesome"];
```

Would like to start at index 3 ("farout") loop through to end of array ("awesome") then continue looping at index 0 through index 2.  Basically beginning an array at some point (other than index 0) and still hit every element in the array.

Comment: Yes I know, I need a For Loop, and yes I know how to do a For Loop, I just don't know how to set it up in such a way of the question I'm asking

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this? - if you're hitting every element in the array - why does it matter?

Comment: Well I have a blackjack game I'm working on for leisure.  I need to be able to do this so I can replace cards that repeat.  I store the repeat values in an array, I then need to loop through them.  Since the array is dynamic, sometimes I have to start at index 3 or 4 or 1 or whatever.  Thanks for asking

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way is to loop through the array using an index as normal, and use the modulus operator with your offset, to get a pointer to the correct place in the array:

```
var myArry = ["cool", "gnarly", "rad", "farout", "awesome"];
var offset = 3;
for( var i=0; i < myArry.length; i++) {
    var pointer = (i + offset) % myArry.length;
    console.log(myArry[pointer]);
}
```

So your loop is a standard loop through every element. You take the current position, plus offset, and get the remainder from that divided by the size of the array. Until you reach the end of the array that will just be the same as i + offset. When you reach the end of the array, the remainder will be zero, and go from there.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6e6cocbt/1/).

Comment: The offset should be 3 for the OP question.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.  I knew how to do this using a series of || in an if, but that doesn't look good and can not be modularized.  Your solution works great.  Could not find anything on Google about this.  Thanx

Comment: this was the algorithm I needed to perfectly animate stacking UI panels that can change in horizontal directions, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Here's what you need:

```
var start = 3;
for(var z=0;z<myArry.length;++z) {
  var idx = (z+start) % myArry.length;
  console.log(myArry[idx]);
}
```

Comment: Didn't even think to use modulas.  Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
var startAt = 3;
for(var index = 0;index<myArry.length;index++){
  console.log(myArry[startAt]);
  if(startAt==myArry.length-1){
        startAt = -1;
  } 
  startAt++;
}
```

Comment: jsbench shows that accepted solution is 73.09 % slower than this answer