# Loop forward then continue from first position -1

Tags: javascript

I am trying to distribute cards to all players. There are 8 seats available. The dealing could start from any position. The example below shows that the starting position is 3 which means cards will be dealt in this order 3-4-5-6-7-8-1-2. If dealing starts at 7 then it would be 7-8-1-2-3-4-5-6 etc.
My current loop below finishes at 8. I'm not sure how to continue.

Here is my code:

```
 var a = 3; //this is the variable starting position
        for (i = a; i < 9; i++) {
            var nextavail = $('#seat' + i).find('.back');
            if (nextavail.length > 0) {
                oPosition.seat = 'seat' + i;
                oPosition.cardid = $(nextavail[0]).data('card');
                break;
            }
```

If I try this:  `for (i = a; i < 9; i++, i == 8 ? 7 : i = 1)` this takes me into an infinity loop. Any ideas?

Comment: This kind of thing is an excellent use of the "modulus" (`%`) operator.  `nextavail = nextavail % 9` will loop you back down to 0.  Add one as needed.

Comment: you are making i = 1 in your for loop it will go on forever

Comment: @theGleep could you please show me an example? I'm a JS beginner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through arrays starting at different index while still looping through entire array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430348/how-to-loop-through-arrays-starting-at-different-index-while-still-looping-throu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var start = 3;
var max = 9;
for (var i=start; i < max + start; i++) {
  var number = (i > max)? i % max : i;
  console.log(number);
}
```

This produces 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2.

Answer (score 0):

The loop ends  for maximum value  i which is less than 9 . if you want  i 
to move 3-4-5-6-7-8-9-1-2

```
 for (j = a-1; j < 8+a ; j++){
   i = j%9 + 1 ;
 // putting the rest of the code of the for loop inside 

 var nextavail = $('#seat' + i).find('.back');
        if (nextavail.length > 0) {
            oPosition.seat = 'seat' + i;
            oPosition.cardid = $(nextavail[0]).data('card');
            break;
        } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 3; //this is the variable starting position
var seats = 8; // seats count
for (var i = 0; i < seats; i++) {
  var currentPosition = (a + i) === seats ? seats : (a + i) % seats;
  var nextavail = $('#seat' + currentPosition).find('.back');
  if (nextavail.length > 0) {
    oPosition.seat = 'seat' + currentPosition;
    oPosition.cardid = $(nextavail[0]).data('card');
    break;
  }
}
```

Try to use modulus operator